# How to Handle Image uploading in WKWebview?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I have use webkit to show url on my app.

when I click on image button(green button in [image]), it shows
camera or photo library.
issue is, when click *Use photo*, the webkit
refresh automatically instead showing on page

- I have already give photo usage, media, camera permission in plist file

my code is

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import Alamofire

class ContinueViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var activityView: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

    func getPostString(params:[String:Any]) -> String{
            var data = [String]()
            for(key, value) in params
            {
                data.append(key + "=\(value)")

            }
            return data.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "&")
    }

    var url: URL?
    var traderCategoryId = 0, tradeSkillId = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webview.navigationDelegate = self
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        webview.uiDelegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        activityView.startAnimating()
        guard let url = self.url else { return }
        var req = URLRequest(url: url)

        let params = ["id" : id,"trader_skills" : tradeSkillId]
        let postString = self.getPostString(params: params)
        req.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        req.httpMethod = "POST"
        req.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        self.webview.load(req)
    }
}

extension ContinueViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityView.stopAnimating()
    }
}

extension UIImagePickerController {
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      //  self.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> issue is, when click Use photo, the webkit refresh automatically instead showing on page

Because you `self.webview.load(req)` in

`override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {`

shows camera or photo library, then return to this page

`func viewWillAppear` called again

`self.webview.load(req)` called again

---

do it simple ,

put `self.webview.load(req)` the relevant in

`override func viewDidLoad() {`